# Find limsup and liminf

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $(r_n)$ be a sequence of real numbers, all in the the interval $(0,1)$, that is dense in $(0,1)$. Let $(x_n)$ be the sequence in given by $x_n:=r^{\frac{1}{n}}$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Find $\limsup_{n\to\infty}x_n$. Is it possible to determine $\liminf_{n\to\infty} x_n?$

$x_n=r^{\frac{1}{n}}=1$ as $n\to\infty$.

So I think $\limsup x_n=1$, Is it correct?

How to determine  $\liminf_{n\to\infty} x_n?$?

Comment: I am confused. What is $r$? and what does $r_n$ have to do with the question? Also, why do you think the limsup is 1?

Answer (score 1):

If $r$ is a fixed positive number, then $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} r^{\frac{1}{n}}=1$.  Therefore $\liminf=\limsup=1$.